# Remove Row(s) Based on Duplicate Values When Comparing 2 Row Cells To Below Row Cells in Same Column in Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to remove (mostly) duplicate rows from a very large spreadsheet.

I can tell that the row is duplicate if the values in two cells per row are the same.

Here is an example:

```
1   a   ewq
1   e   weq
1   h   ewq
2   b   ddsfa
2   b   as
2   i   d
3   c   fdsa
3   f   ads
4   d   fd
4   g   as
```

In this example, the fourth and fifth rows would be duplicate because the values in column "A" and column "B" are the same. The deciding values will always be found in the same columns.

I would like to get rid of either the fourth or fifth row based on the duplicate status and shift the rows up.

I'm not even sure if this is close, but this is what I have so far (I'm getting a mismatch error):

```
Sub MasterRemoveDuplicates()
Dim Master As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set Master = Workbooks("Master.csv").Worksheets("Master")

 Last = 1

For i = 1 To 18211 
If Range("A" & i) And Range("B" & i) <> Range("A" & (i + 1)) And Range("B" & (i + 1)) Then
Worksheets("Master").Rows(Last).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Last = i + 1

Master.Activate
End If
Next i

MsgBox "Completed!", vbInformation, ""

reset_settings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Everything is in the same worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel. There is a ready-made RemoveDuplicates command.

```
Sub MasterRemoveDuplicates()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Workbooks("Master.csv").Worksheets("Master")

        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2))

            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

        End With

    End With

    MsgBox "Completed!", vbInformation, ""

reset_settings:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this! I knew I was overthinking it. The only correction I had to make was to change '.Offset(0,1)' to '.Offset(0,2)' so the entire used part of the row (3 columns have info in the example above) would be deleted rather than only the first two. For anyone who reads this, the last value in 'Offset' will be the upper limit of your used cells in the row to be purged. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in if statement

try this:

```
    If Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & (i + 1)) And Range("B" & i) <> Range("B" & (i + 1))    Then
```

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy M. ! Dumb mistake on my part...I tried running it with the fix and don't get an error anymore. Unfortunately, my shoddy code deleted more than it was supposed to. Since user10862412's code worked, I'm just going to abandon mine and go with his. Thanks again for your help!